# Android : Bug on Firebase using persistence with orderByChild() and limitToLast()?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, persistence

I've got a weird behavior on Firebase using persistence, orderByChild() and limitToLast methods.

Here is my base code.  Please note that my app is always online. (You'll find below all the steps to reproduce the issue and a github link to the sample project)

Enabling persistence in my Application class:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Add a score to a user:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores")
.child("users")
.child("user1") //add a new user
.child("score") //along with a new score
.setValue(1);
```

Get the best 3 scores:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores")
.child("users")
.orderByChild("score")
.limitToLast(3)
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

Here is the workflow to reproduce the issue:

1. clear your firebase database
2. Display all DB to confirm that everything is empty
3. Display the best 3 scores to confirm that everything is empty
4. Add a new score : (user1, 1)
5. Display the best 3 scores. Result = (user1, 1) => OK
6. Add a new score : (user2, 2)
7. Display the best 3 scores. Result = (user1, 1), (user2, 2) => OK

Remove the App

Install the app again

8. Display the best 3 scores. Result = (user1, 1), (user2, 2) => OK
9. Add 2 new scores : (user3, 3) and (user4, 4)
10. **Display the best 3 scores. Result = (user1, 1), (user2, 2) => NOK**
11. Display all DB => (user1, 1), (user2, 2), (user3, 3), (user4, 4) => OK

**So in this specific use case, the main issue is that the "get the best 3 scores" request, that uses orderByChild and limitToLast methods, is not update after adding some new scores.**
(but it worked in step 7 !)

I've uploaded the Android project on my github : https://github.com/MalikDE/FirebaseOrderByChildIssue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

If you attach a `ChildEventListener` you *will* get a separate `onChildAdded` for the new score straight away.

**Explanation of the behavior:**

One of the guarantees that the Firebase Database makes is that it will never fire an event with incomplete data. Unfortunately, being a schemaless database, it is sometimes not clear to Firebase whether data is complete.

When you use a `ValueEventListener`, Firebase will only fire the event once it knows the complete data for that location. Since it doesn't realize that the new score is a complete new child, it doesn't fire an event with that added score.

We'd love to detect this better, but it is unlikely we'll be able to do so within the current API without breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks Frank.
Just tried something else : when I reach step 10, I `setValue(null)` on the root node, to clear the DB. The "get the best 3 scores" request now returns null. I then add some new scores and attach a new `ValueEventListener`. It returns null ... Despite the fact that everything was cleared, it seems that Firebase still doesn't realize that it is a complete data.

Comment: When you reset the entire location, Firebase knows that it has a complete value (or in this case "lack of a value") again, so it can fire the event. Then adding individual child nodes breaks that contract. Essentially the database has no way to differentiate between the cases where you 1) add a complete child 2) add a few properties of a child.

Comment: In order to avoid new mistakes, I'd love to have a technical tutorial on that topic :) Anyway, I found a workaround for my issue: using `addValueEventListener` seems to work well. The trade-off is that I always have to use Firebase in a realtime way.